# TV-out worked, now doesn't. May the problem be the cable, TV, driver, OS, graphic card?

Tags: s-video, composite-video, tv-out

I have a CRT TV hooked to the PC, which once worked great, now doesn't.
I can't consider getting a newer TV, this one is used in an MAME arcade cabinet so it has to be a CRT for best old school look and feel.
It's connected through the TV-out connector of my graphic card.
When it worked, I had Windows XP, the same PC and the same card. Now I have windows 7, not sure if the OS switch caused the malfunction as I don't use the TV-out all the time.
Can it be an upgrade of the Nvidia driver?
I thought it may be the S-video to RCA cable, but tried 3 different cables and neither worked.
In fact, one of them, that unlike the other two, has a single RCA output connector instead of two, behaves differently, although it doesn't work, but it does the following:
When I open the NVidia settings panel, or when I change a setting and click `Apply` then the TV flashes for a split second and you can see the windows screen, but then it goes back to blank.
So any clues what can be failing here, and some advice?
Possible failures, please comment on the one you suspect the most:

- NVidia driver version
- Windows version
- Cable
- Graphic card's TV out
- other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to troubleshoot, changing one element at a time. My suggested order:

- Cables (which you've already dealt with.)
- TV settings. I find them to at times be tough to navigate.
- Ports. Are you sure you used the same TV inputs as before? And the same PC output? Are there other possibilities?
- Windows version. (Borrow a laptop with XP or Vista or something).
- Driver update or rollback. Can you identify the version number of the XP version? Is there a W7 or Vista version at similar version obtainable?

I recall an issue of seeing the brief PC image on TV. I'll edit if I remember where/when/how.

Comment: Thanks. 
TV settings: it has none relevant to this issue, the menu is very simple.
Ports: yes, both outputs and inputs are the same that used to work. No other possibilities.
Gonna check the rest.